# Multi-threading issue with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I currently need to do an **automated** work, and I want to speed up using **threadings**
However, the issue is that when I start **2 threads or more**, the program will **automatically closes until it reached 1 thread**.
Any solution to this?.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import random
import threading

def ChromeMetamask():
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_extension("metaMaskextension.crx")
    ChromeMetamask.web = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    return ChromeMetamask.web

def StreamTeam():
    ...
    ChromeMetamask.web.quit()
    


def run(x):
    print("Running thread" ,x)
    sleep(x)
    while True:
        try:
            ChromeMetamask()
            print("Creating wallet of thread" ,x)
            CreateWallet()
            print("Working on thread" ,x)
            StreamTeam()
            print("Thread " + str(x) + " has completed")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Thread " + str(x) + " encounters an error, restarting")
            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = int(input("Enter number of threads: "))
    threads = []
    for x in range(1,thread+1):
        threads += [threading.Thread(target = run, args ={x}, )]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Comment: What is the output your code produces?

Comment: It's just a code to automate my work on a form. BTW, it cannot run 2 or more chrome instances at the same time, so im asking people about this :(